# What was Weierstrass's counterexample to the Dirichlet Principle?

Tags: ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy, complex-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Shortly after his work on the foundations of geometry David Hilbert turned his attention to finding a suitable statement of the Dirichlet principle, from which to prove the Riemann mapping theorem and vindicate the topological program for complex analysis.  Based on comments made in letters to Frege a major motivation for Hilbert's foray into geometry and independence proofs was to investigate the Archimedean axiom.  Specifically, Hilbert mentions (to Frege) Dehn's dissertation on the Archimedean axiom and Legendre's theorem.  This leads me to think that conformal mappings were on Hilbert's mind and to guess that Weierstrass's counterexample somehow concerned the Archimedean property.  But I can't find anything in the secondary history/philosophy of math literature that quite puts all the pieces of the puzzle together--that Weierstrass had a counter-example is mentioned but details are skirted--and qua philosopher I'm bumping up against my mathematical horizons in piecing it together myself.

Comment: It might just be me being silly but could you be a little bit more specific as to what the exact claim that the counterexample is a counterexample to is?

Comment: Have you looked at Monna's book _Dirichlet's Principle: A Mathematical Comedy of Errors and Its Influence on the Development of Analysis_? If I remember correctly he had a short description of Weierstrass's counterexample. 

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_principle

Comment: Not in my library, so I'll have to interlibrary loan it.  In the mean time I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: On why the Dirichlet principle approach to Riemann Mapping would be bad I remember Tom Korner mentioning both 'Weierstrass' and something like 'the domain obtained by taking a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and pushing in the North Pole with a pencil so that it has a sharp point pointing in on itself' in close-by setences, but I don't know/can't remember if this is actually the Weierstrass example. 

Comment: No, conterexamples to the Dirichlet Principle concern Plateau's problem mostly, initial repairs by Courant rather than Hilbert, see Richard Courant, "Dirichlet's Principle, Conformal Mapping, and Minimal Surfaces" Dover Publications, or Lectures on Minimal Surfaces, vol. 1 by J. C. C. Nitsche. The other stuff, non-Archimedean fields, is completely unrelated, see Robin Hartshorne, Geometry: Euclid and Beyond. This concerns models for non-Euclidean geometry without using continuity axioms at all, no real numbers in sight. 

Comment: This sort of just thickens the plot for me.  It is known that Dehn's notes include a unpublished proof of the Jordan curve theorem (see Guggenheimer, 1977) dated 1899 using only incidence and order axioms.  Again, I'm straining at my horizons here but the minimal surface problems are posed using Jordan curves, right?  I can't believe that Hilbert's concerns were purely geometric, especially because of his algebraic understanding of the axioms.

Comment: I don't see how to define a minimal surface in the case of $\mathbf F^3,$ where $\mathbf F$ is an arbitrary Euclidean field. It is not possible in general to define an area function for all interesting regions in  $\mathbf F^2.$ You ought also to read the new 4th edition of Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries by Marvin Jay Greenberg. Any similarities between the two problems seem to me, at best, expressions of Hilbert's general concern with firming up foundations after various disturbances caused by Cantor's set theory and disputes over the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Thanks, found a download of the Courant reference you gave below and am finding that particularly helpful.  I'm more philosopher than mathematician.  I'm onto this topic because of philosophical questions raised by Stewart Shapiro in "Categories, Structures, and the Frege-Hilbert Correspondence".  My geometry and general topology are ok, but analysis (especially complex analysis) is a slog.  I'm trying to say something about Hilbert's mathematical motivations for the philosophical and foundational positions he takes, but maybe you're right to suggest I'm a bit taken in by itsallconnectedism.

Comment: I was unable to find your email address. If you look up mine at   
$$ $$   
http://www.ams.org/cml    
$$ $$
and email me I can send you a pdf of a 22-page article by Marvin Greenberg, M.A.A. Monthly, March 2010, pages 198-219, called "Old and New Results in the Foundations of Elementary Plane Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries. At least it would give you some sense of how the Archimedean field axiom fits into this, specifically what happens when it does not apply. Plus many nice references listed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Weierstrass simply observed that not every problem in the calculus of variations would have a solution. He considered the example
$$D[y]=\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\left(\frac{d y}{dx}\right)^2dx\to \min,$$
where the functional $D[y]$ is minimized over continuous functions having piecewise continuous first derivatives in $[-1,1]$ and satisfying the boundary conditions
$y(-1)=0$, $y(1)=1$. He proved that although there is a minimizing sequence $y_n=y_n(.)$ which makes $D[y_n]$ arbitrarily small, the minimal value of zero is never actually attained.

Weierstrass's example called into question the *a priori* validity of Dirichlet's principle. However, it did not completely refute the specific applications of Dirichlet's principle to boundary value problems for Laplace's equation developed by Green, Dirichlet, Riemann and others. It simply implied that the particular result required by Riemann would need a formal proof, which Riemann had not provided. For that reason some people refer to this example as Weierstrass's critique rather than Weierstrass's counterexample.

The story is briefly discussed in [*"A History of Analysis"*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CVRZEXFVsZkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=A+history+of+analysis&source=bl&ots=ibDC2FGy1i&sig=frWcc8aQWudQ9weQCKHMmUm6mKo&hl=en&ei=Eke3TLTOHcvFswbrw-iSCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) edited by Hans Niels Jahnke.

Comment: Weierstrass's example is also mentioned in the Wikipedia article  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Dirichlet.27s_principle

Comment: The original reference is *Über das sogenannte Dirichlet'sche Princip*, a communication read before the Royal Academy of Sciences in Göttingen. You can find it in Weierstraß's *Mathematische Werke* http://www.archive.org/details/mathematischewer02weieuoft (pp. 49-54).

Answer (score 9):

I think I vaguely remember what the counterexpample was, but not the details. So if someone can fill it in it'd be great! (I'm putting this in CW mode for that reason.)

The idea is based on knowing explicitly the Green's function in the disk. The goal is to construct a continuous function $g$ on the boundary of the unit disk, such that it is the trace of some smooth function $f$ where $\triangle f = 0$ in the disk, and where the energy integral $\int_D |\partial f|^2 dx = \infty$.

The construction itself, I think, was based on finding a sequence of harmonic functions $f_k$ such that in the interior of the disk $\sum \partial^\alpha f_k$ converges pointwise for any derivative with multiindex $\alpha$ (but of course the sum fails to converge for any derivative on the boundary, so the final function only extends continuously to the boundary). the Trick is that these functions are chosen with specific boundary values, so that using the Green's function one can estimate (from below) the size of their gradients near the boundary. Then one just need to make sure that the blow-up rate of the gradient dominates the distance to the boundary, so the energy integral will fail to converge in a neighborhood of the boundary.

Since the energy integral of the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation is infinite, the solution obviously is not a minimizer of the energy integral, thus contradicting Dirichlet's principle.

Comment: likely to be in Richard Courant, "Dirichlet's Principle, Conformal Mapping, and Minimal Surfaces" Dover Publications

Comment: Willie, I was just at a bookstore, Courant gives an example, due to Hadamard, where the original formulation of the Dirchlet principle fails (integral undefined or something), but there is a solution on the unit disc with $\Delta u = 0$ and with the given boundary data. 

Comment: Ah, I may have confused Weierstrass and Hadamard on this matter. Thanks, Will!

Comment: Willie, I found a biography of Courant by Peter D. Lax and a book called Hilbert-Courant by Constance Reid. Weierstrass objected first, while Riemann was still alive. Lax says "Weierstrass even gave an example of a fourth order functional whose minimum is not assumed by any function." Hadamard's example is later, 1906. 


Comment: @Will: Yes, but Hadamard's example is of different nature. That said, similar example was discovered by Friedrich Prym around 1870's.

Comment: If someone is interested, the explicit function is $u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}r^{n!}\sin(n!\theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

To lay bare the mathematical facts, beyond historical, a basic result in elementary theory of Hilbert spaces is that a (non-empty) closed convex set in a Hilbert space has a unique element of minimal norm.

Perhaps surprisingly or disappointingly, the analogue for the naturally-occurring Banach spaces of continuous or $L^1$ or other classes of functions can fail either by non-existence of the minimizer, or non-uniqueness. And this is not pathological. Standard examples: in $L^1[a,b]$, the subset of $f$ with $\int_0^1 f = 1$ has infinitely-many norm-minimizing elements; meanwhile, in $C^o[0,2]$, there is *no* norm-minimizing function among those with $\int_0^1 f - \int_1^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

A short introduction and connection to Jacob Steiner's proofs of Dido's Problem can be found in Perron, O., Zur Existenzfrage eines Maximums oder Minimums, Deutsche Math.-Ver. 22, 140-144 (1913).